# How is "create view" evaluated in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a - maybe simple - question about how `create view` and `select ... from viewname` is evaluated. I know how to create views and use them, but I have to explain the procedure of those two commands graphically and with text for my school.

Well, I do the following (I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 at the moment, but that should not matter, does it? I would like to know it for MySQL too, if there are differences):

```
-- create a Schema for the test
create schema TEMP
go

-- create the view
create view TEMP.VLT as
select LNR,TNR,MENGE
from LTP.LTP
go

-- select the data from the view
select * from TEMP.VLT
```

A `view` is just something like an alias for a select query, which is evaluated in something like a subquery, right? If so, am I right, that

```
select * from TEMP.VLT
```

is the same as

```
select * from (select LNR,TNR,MENGE from LTP.LTP) as VLT
```

?

I mean, I know that it gives the same result, but is it actually evaluated the same way, or am I wrong?

Thank you for responsing!
eisenbahnfan

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the code is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you - but, as I said, I wanted to know for for mysql too, if there are any differences. So I thought, it might be ok to use this tag too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct at a very high level.  First, views can differ among databases.  MySQL, in particular, has a bunch of limitations such as no subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  But, in fact, MySQL pretty much operates the way you describe.

You have the right understanding in general. The code of the view is merged into the query where it is being referenced.  Here is specific language in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190237(v=sql.105).aspx):

> When an SQL statement references a nonindexed view, the parser and
>   query optimizer analyze the source of both the SQL statement and the
>   view and then resolve them into a single execution plan. There is not
>   one plan for the SQL statement and a separate plan for the view.

There is a type of view called "indexed views" which actually materialize the data.  In this case, the code for the view is not actually run, but results are used in the query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! ........... But I have tried the subquery in the from clause in MySQL, and it worked (`mysql> select * from (select * from test) as X;`)

Comment: @eisenbahnfan . . .That doesn't work in a view.  You can review the limitation here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. In SQL a.view is just a logical abstraction. 
Not to be confused with materialized views (in oracle, other db have different names) which instead contains replicated data taken via a query at fixed time intervals

Comment: Thank you very much for this very fast response!     
So you mean, in Oracle there the data is something like a copy, which is updated in something like a cronjob or after a insert/update trigger? (I know that this is a little bit off-topic now as I asked for MS SQL-Svr and MySQL, but I am interested in that now ;-))

Comment: No. In oracle a view is a logical structure which 'hides' a query. Moreover it does exist a structure called materialized view which behave as you just said